# Code for LCM of order of element in GAP

Tags: gap

Is there an easier way to write the LCM part of this code?  Gap only allows two arguments for `LCM_INT`.

```
SigmaSet := function(GROUP, g1, g2)
local S, g3;
S := [ ];
g3:= g2^-1 * g1^-1;
g_elts := [g1, g2, g3];
for g in GROUP do
    for j in [0..LCM_INT( Order(g1), LCM_INT( Order(g2), Order(g3) ) ) ] do
        for i in [1..3] do
            S := UnionSet(S, [g*g_elts[i]^j*g^-1 ]);
        od; 
    od; 
od;
return S;
end;
```

Comment: Do you know about [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)? It is for code enthusiasts and should still work for math questions.

Comment: No, sorry I don't.  Thank you.

Comment: `Lcm( List( g_elts, Order ) )` should do the trick, I think.

Comment: The user function is `Lcm` and takes an arbitrary (finite) number of arguments. `LCM_INT` is an internal function.

Comment: Thank you both.